# Android host website on phone

Tags: java, android, http, google-chrome

What approach can I take to solve my problem such that my Android app hosts a website (on whatever port > 1024) and also features a way to allow/block incoming client. So far i have tried manually opening a ServerSocket and injecting html then closing the socket, however it only works most of the time and only with Google Chrome...anyone have other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some small servlet container like jetty - pure java and lightweight enough to fit a phone.  Then you can register your servlets and maybe deploy complete war archive

Comment: Jetty need JRE right?? even if used, Wont jetty consume too much of memory??

Comment: AFAIK, jetty is really lightweight and uses nothing not available on android. And when I like to server websites from phone, it is too late to worry about memory consunmption

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [iJetty](http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/).  They basically ported a fully-functional Jetty implementation to Android.  I've used it before both as a servlet container (deploying WAR files to it) and as an embedded server in an application I wrote.  Getting it to work inside of another application takes some doing, but can definitely be done.  You also have access to the source code so you can modify as needed.